# using akka streams to go over mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka, akka-stream, reactivemongo

I have a collection of people in mongo, and I want to go over each person in the collection as a stream, and for each person call a method that is performing api call, changing the model, and inserting to a new collection in mongo.

It looks like this:

```
  def processPeople()(implicit m: Materializer): Future[Unit] = {

    val peopleSource: Source[Person, Future[State]] = collection.find(json()).cursor[Person]().documentSource()

    peopleSource.runWith(Sink.seq[Person]).map(people => {
      people.foreach(person => {
        changeModelAndInsertToNewCollection(person)
      }) 
    })
  }
```

but this is not working...the part of changing the model seems like is working, but the insert to mongo is not working.

It looks like also the method is not starting right away, there some processing going behind before for a min before it starts....do you see the issue?

Comment: Using `Sink.seq[Person]` makes it read all data from the collection first and only then start calling `people.foreach` on the fetched data. This would explain the delay if you have a lot of data in the source collection. The problem with inserts must lay in the implementation of `changeModelAndInsertToNewCollection`, there is no insert code in your example

Comment: @yahor my problem was instead of using runWith I should of used runForeach..

Comment: Just one tip on this. Using `runForeach` doesn't do any back pressure so it is quite likely you load everything into memory and submit a lot of asynchronous tasks in a short period of time if `changeModelAndInsertToNewCollection` is asynchronous. You can use `mapAsync` to control back pressure

Comment: @yahor thanks buddy. what I did was when declaring my peopleSource I added ```.documentSource().throttle(50, 1.second)``` and this gives me the back pressure..

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

```
def changeModelAndInsertToNewCollection(person:Person) : Future[Boolean] ={
//Todo : call mongo api to update the person
???
}

def processPeople()(implicit m: Materializer): Future[Done] = {
val numberOfConcurrentUpdate = 10

val peopleSource: Source[Person, Future[State]] =
  collection
    .find(json())
    .cursor[Person]()
    .documentSource()

peopleSource
  .mapAsync(numberOfConcurrentUpdate)(changeModelAndInsertToNewCollection)
  withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(Supervision.restartingDecider))
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)}
```

**Solution 2 :**
using [Alpakka](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/mongodb.html) as akka stream connector for mongo

```
val source: Source[Document, NotUsed] =
MongoSource(collection.find(json()).cursor[Person]().documentSource())

source.runWith(MongoSink.updateOne(2, collection))
```